# how to check the Database used in loadrunner when sending a HTTP requests or getting Responses

Tags: postgresql, loadrunner

we used to use sap as DB for our raw data, when I make a load Test for example to get our business partner, all the requests access the sap dB, and I got the response of the business partners, when I send the following request code:

```
web_custom_request(MDM_GET_BUSINESS_PARTNER, 
  "URL={TEST_ENV_HOSTNAME}/api/v3/clients/{BUSINESS_CONTEXT}/customers/{GCID}/businessPartner",
  "Method=GET", 
  "EncType=application/xml", "Resource=1",
  "Referer=Loadrunner",
LAST);
```

Here as you can see there is no mention of SAP DB or whatever DB are used, and now we move (migrate) from SAP DB to PostgreSQL.

**My question**: how to check the HTTP Requests send and their Responses are using which DB's (SAP or PostgreSQL)? is there any method solution for that, because as you can see above, the request goes to the `{TEST_ENV_HOSTNAME}` which is a parameter file, and there is no mention of any DB.

Answer (score 0):

Speak to your application architects.  You are operating a one architectural tier removed from the database, at the web tier.  So, only an architectural diagram can solve your information needs

Comment: but they want me to test the new DB (PostgreSQL), since they migrate to it now...

Comment: Run a profiler while you are running the test.  You should not be collecting parameters at run time from the same database which is used under test as this will have the effect of distorting performance with the additional load of sessions and queries against the DB which are not there in production.

Comment: thank you...but this is a very big stuff...I've never do it before